# Magento2 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Aws\manifest()

Tags: magento2

Magento2 getting following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Aws\manifest() in /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php:188
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(327): Aws\AwsClient->__construct(Array)
#1 /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/app/code/Thai/S3/Console/Command/StorageExportCommand.php(98): Aws\S3\S3Client->__construct(Array)
#2 [internal function]: Thai\S3\Console\Command\StorageExportCommand->Thai\S3\Console\Command\{closure}()
#3 /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(187): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/app/code/Thai/S3/Console/Command/StorageExportCommand.php(133): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('adminhtml', Object(Closure))
#5 /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Thai\S3\Console\Command\StorageExportCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Obj in /mnt/data/home/mo2te673/public_html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 188
```

after running following command

> php bin/magento s3:storage:export

I have installed this module

> https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3